# Can an American sue their own state directly in the federal Supreme Court?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction, us-supreme-court, federalism, governmental-liability

According to Article III, Section 2 of the constitution,

> The judicial Power shall extend to all Cases, in Law and Equity, arising under this Constitution, the Laws of the United States, and Treaties made, or which shall be made, under their Authority;—to all Cases affecting Ambassadors, other public Ministers and Consuls;—to all Cases of admiralty and maritime Jurisdiction;—to Controversies to which the United States shall be a Party;—to Controversies between two or more States;—between a State and Citizens of another State;—between Citizens of different States;—between Citizens of the same State claiming Lands under Grants of different States, and between a State, or the Citizens thereof, and foreign States, Citizens or Subjects.

This defines the jurisdiction of the federal judiciary. For example, the federal judiciary has jurisdiction to hear cases where a citizen alleges that their own state is violating one of their rights granted by the federal constitution and seeks injunctive relief, since that falls under "arising under this Constitution".

Furthermore,

> In all Cases affecting Ambassadors, other public Ministers and Consuls, and those in which a State shall be Party, the supreme Court shall have original Jurisdiction.

My understanding of "original jurisdiction" is that it basically means "you can file this kind of case in this court". And since this is in the constitution, Congress can't take it away.

However, as far as I can tell, it's not actually allowed for an American to sue their own state directly in the Supreme Court. They have to file in a federal district court and then appeal the decision if they don't like it. Legally speaking, why is that?

Comment: "They have to file in a federal district court and then appeal the decision if they don't like it." This is incorrect. A state cannot be sued by a citizen of a state in federal district court without its permission (sometimes granted in bankruptcy cases). Typically, this is dealt with by having citizens sue a public official of a state and local government, either personally or in an official capacity only, rather than suing the state itself.

Answer (score 6):

The Eleventh Amendment has generally been construed to bar suits against a state by citizens of that state in federal court. There are all sorts of caveats, though, and it's possible that the doctrine is still evolving.

The text of the [Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/amendmentxi) reads:

> The judicial power of the United States shall not be construed to extend to any suit in law or equity, commenced or prosecuted against one of the United States by citizens of another state, or by citizens or subjects of any foreign state.

It doesn't contain explicit language prohibiting the citizens of a state from suing it in federal court. That extension surfaced throughout the 1880s and was formalized in [*Hans v. Louisiana*](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/134/1/), 134 U.S. 1 (1890). [*Seminole Tribe v. Florida*](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1995/94-12), 517 U.S. 44 (1996), lends support to *Hans*, albeit as a 5-4 decision.

Cornell has a nice article on the current and historical view of [sovereign immunity](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution-conan/amendment-11/state-sovereign-immunity). It notes that the Supreme Court has left a number of important questions unanswered—including the nature of the states' immunity. It likewise tries to wrestle with the Article III question.

Comment: Sovereign immunity doesn't apply in cases where the plaintiff seeks injunctive relief against the state for violating a constitutional right (or a federal law). Clearly, in such cases, an American can sue their own state in federal court. My question is: what stops them from filing directly with the Supreme Court rather than a district court?

Comment: @Brian The Supreme Court's original jurisdiction can be either exclusive or concurrent. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I'm aware that original jurisdiction can be concurrent. But doesn't that mean that the plaintiff has the *choice* of which court to file in? Legally, what stops a private citizen from choosing the Supreme Court (as opposed to a district court) as the venue for filing their complaint against their state?

Comment: Setting aside the Eleventh Amendment question, even when the Supreme Court has concurrent jurisdiction, it still has discretion to hear a case or not. The Court can prevent forum shopping by way of [Rule 17](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/supct/rule_17). The rule governs the Court's original jurisdiction and requires that initial pleadings be preceded by a motion for leave to file.

Comment: I thought that original jurisdiction implies the absence of discretion, e.g., if one state wants to sue another state in the Supreme Court, the Court may not refuse to hear the case unless there is some specific reason why it's barred, or the proper filing procedure is not followed. If the Supreme Court also has original jurisdiction in the case of an individual suing their own state, what gives them the discretion to refuse to exercise that original jurisdiction?

Comment: There's a sequence of acts of Congress that establish the Supreme Court's discretion. (The State v. State example isn't a great one because those cases fall under the Court's exclusive original jurisdiction.)

Comment: "Sovereign immunity doesn't apply in cases where the plaintiff seeks injunctive relief against the state for violating a constitutional right (or a federal law)." Generally speaking, you still can't sue a state in federal court for injunctive relief (without its consent, sometimes granted in bankruptcy cases, e.g.), but you can sue a suitable official of a state in the official's official capacity in federal court for injunctive relief. This is due to the 11th Amendment as interpreted by the courts in a manner reflecting its intended and not its literal meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Under [28 USC 1254](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1254),

> Cases in the courts of appeals may be reviewed by the Supreme Court by
> the following methods: (1) By writ of certiorari granted upon the
> petition of any party to any civil or criminal case, before or after
> rendition of judgment or decree;

or by certification by a court of appeals. Additionally, under [28 USC 1651(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1651),

> The Supreme Court and all courts established by Act of Congress may
> issue all writs necessary or appropriate in aid of their respective
> jurisdictions and agreeable to the usages and principles of law.

So it is allowed, but highly disfavored. [This article](https://www.scotusblog.com/2018/12/power-versus-discretion-extraordinary-relief-and-the-supreme-court/) discusses extraordinary relief by SCOTUS and [the court rules](https://www.supremecourt.gov/ctrules/2019RulesoftheCourt.pdf) that work against such a path, bypassing lower courts. Rule 11 on "writs of certiorari before judgment, provides that such a petition will be granted 'only upon a showing that the case is of such imperative public importance as to justify deviation from normal appellate practice and to require immediate determination in this Court.'" Rule 20 maintains that an extraordinary writ "is not a matter of right, but of discretion sparingly exercised." It must be proven that "adequate  relief  cannot  be  obtained  in any  other  form  or  from  any  other  court".

Comment: Petitioning for certiorari is basically the opposite of invoking the Court's original jurisdiction, which is what the OP seems to be asking about.